# What do these network terms mean? (br0 etc)

Tags: networking, snmp

New to SNMP, playing around with Cacti and PRTG. Can someone explain what these stand for to me?
I've tried on Google and it hasnt returned much information relevant to this (I dont even know what the term is, Network Interfaces?)

lo 
cpcs0
br0

I figured atm0 meant Asynchronous Transfer Mode 0 & wl0 meant Wireless LAN 0

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lo - Loopback(http://linux.about.com/od/lna_guide/a/gdelna47t00.htm)

br0 -  [Linux ethernet bridge](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bridge)

cpcs - common part convergence sublayer(http://ntrg.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2/atm/ATMadapt.html)